# Aptana Python unable to launch

Tags: python-2.7, pydev, aptana, aptana3

I am having a hard time launching in Aptana Studio. I keep getting this message:

["unable to launch"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQcgC.png)

Any help on how I can get past this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use **F9** to launch and if you configured Eclipse as the PyDev getting started manual suggested (on the running/debugging session: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html), **Ctrl+F11** can be used to relaunch your last launch -- ideally, go through the whole getting started manual (http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html -- it should be really worth it to get you up to speed on PyDev).

As a note, the **PyDev** version included with **Aptana Studio** is really **ancient** (so, my suggestion is either getting the latest **Eclipse/PyDev** or using **LiClipse**: http://www.liclipse.com, which has **PyDev** builtin).